# Android : Nested if statements jump between statements

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my Android application I am trying to read an xml file using XMLPullParser using the following code:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
                {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                    {
                        s = xpp.getName();
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("container"))
                        {
                            state = stateContainer;
                            con = new Container();
                            con.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                            con.setParentId(xpp.getAttributeValue(1));
                            con.setRestricted(xpp.getAttributeValue(2));
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) 
                        {
                            state = stateTitle;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            state = stateUnknown;
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) 
                    {
                        s = xpp.getText();
                        if (state == stateTitle) 
                        {
                            con.setTitle(s);
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
                    {
                        s = xpp.getText();
                        if (xpp.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("container")) 
                        {
                            listAdapter.add(con);
                        }
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                }
```

However, it seems to jump into the line 'listAdapter.add(con);' when none of the other if clauses are true in the other if statements. For example:

`else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)` returns `true`. It then tries `if (state == stateTitle)` which returns `false`. It should jump to `eventType == xpp.next();` but instead goes to `listAdapter.add(con);` which is nested in a different if statement. This also happens with some other if statements.

I would say I'm no beginner when it comes to programming but I can not seem to work out where this problem is coming from!

Thanks

Comment: When I get condition problems, I usually log the values I'm testing.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no magic.

If, while debugging you see the control flow acting as you describe it, then it seems likely that the code you are executing does not match the source.  Try doing a clean and a full rebuild.

Comment: I have tried cleaning it earlier. Forgive my ignorance as I'm not use to eclipse, but is cleaning it and then running it again rebuilding?

Comment: Yes.  That should have sync'd the code with the source.  If you didn't try it, try a clean all to force a complete rebuild.  not just a clean of that project.  You can also turn off automatic build and do the builds manually.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, haven't been able to get onto this for a bit. I tried a clean all and also uninstalled it from the phone but I'm still getting the problem. Also, for the line "if (xpp.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("container"))" it returns true even if xpp.getText() is title.